# How to make Lucene.NET Query '#' and '+' characters?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

How to make Lucene.NET Query '#' and '+' characters ?

Like "C#" and "C++"

Note : i use NHibernate.Search

Comment: are you sure they are not stored or are you trying to query with these characters and you get the wrong results?

Comment: just take a look with Luke, characters are well stored, but i effectively get wrong results...

Comment: i edited my question according to that

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598465/handling-as-a-special-character-in-lucene-search

Answer (score 0):

This will work, it all depends upon how your index is built. does your analyzer throw away these symbols? It also depends upon how the query is getting built, it all boils down to what Terms are getting indexed and what Terms you are searching with.

If you are using the QueryParser to create the lucene Query object, you will have to escape special characters such as the + by adding a \ in front of it.

example:

```
string query = @"2\+2";
```